# Magento 2 - All Products Page with filters and Pagination

Tags: magento2, product, category, magento-enterprise, magento-2.2.5

I need to create a page where product collection from all categories or you can say from root level category (`Default Category`) generally it has id `2`.

I need to make sure that the page is look like normal category where filter can be applied on product collection like `brand`, `color` and `size` etc and all toolbar related functionality `sortby`, `pagination` etc

I want to figure out the best approach how it can be done?

P.S: I don't need a solution like make new category and attach all category products to it.

Any help, experience and knowledge sharing would be appreciated.

Comment: I used Amasty landing page module as a start and modified that.

Comment: Not interested in any paid or 3rd party extension solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently did the same sort of work. First you need to override Category block because you want the All products page just like category page. In order to get more understanding check getCurrentCategory function which set the current category to root category

Path: `app\code\Vendor\AllProducts\Block\Category\View.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\AllProducts\Block\Category;

/**
 * Class View
 * @api
 * @package Magento\Catalog\Block\Category
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * Catalog layer
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer
     */
    protected $_catalogLayer;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category
     */
    protected $_categoryHelper;

    protected $priceHelper;

    protected $_storeManager;

    protected $categoryRepository;

    protected $_request;

    protected $productFactory;

    protected $eavconfig;   
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $priceHelper,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavconfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
        $this->priceHelper = $priceHelper;
        $this->_catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->eavconfig = $eavconfig;

        parent::__construct($context, $layerResolver, $registry, $categoryHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();


        $this->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Breadcrumbs::class);

        $category = $this->getCurrentCategory();
        if ($category) {
            $title = $category->getMetaTitle();
            if ($title) {
                $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set($title);
            }
            $description = $category->getMetaDescription();
            if ($description) {
                $this->pageConfig->setDescription($description);
            }
            $keywords = $category->getMetaKeywords();
            if ($keywords) {
                $this->pageConfig->setKeywords($keywords);
            }
            if ($this->_categoryHelper->canUseCanonicalTag()) {
                $this->pageConfig->addRemotePageAsset(
                    $category->getUrl(),
                    'canonical',
                    ['attributes' => ['rel' => 'canonical']]
                );
            }

            $pageMainTitle = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('page.main.title');
            if ($pageMainTitle) {
                $pageMainTitle->setPageTitle($this->getCurrentCategory()->getName());
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getProductListHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('product_list');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve current category model object
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
     */

    //**** This function set the current category to root level category which is 2 in my case ****//
    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {
        if (!$this->hasData('current_category')) {

            if ($this->_request->getModuleName() == "allproducts"){
            $category = $this->categoryRepository->get(2, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
            }
            else {
            $category = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_category');
            }
            $this->setData('current_category', $category);
        }

        return $this->getData('current_category');
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCmsBlockHtml()
    {
        if (!$this->getData('cms_block_html')) {
            $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \Magento\Cms\Block\Block::class
            )->setBlockId(
                $this->getCurrentCategory()->getLandingPage()
            )->toHtml();
            $this->setData('cms_block_html', $html);
        }
        return $this->getData('cms_block_html');
    }

    /**
     * Check if category display mode is "Products Only"
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isProductMode()
    {
        return $this->getCurrentCategory()->getDisplayMode() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::DM_PRODUCT;
    }

    /**
     * Check if category display mode is "Static Block and Products"
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isMixedMode()
    {
        return $this->getCurrentCategory()->getDisplayMode() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::DM_MIXED;
    }

    /**
     * Check if category display mode is "Static Block Only"
     * For anchor category with applied filter Static Block Only mode not allowed
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isContentMode()
    {
        $category = $this->getCurrentCategory();
        $res = false;
        if ($category->getDisplayMode() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::DM_PAGE) {
            $res = true;
            if ($category->getIsAnchor()) {
                $state = $this->_catalogLayer->getState();
                if ($state && $state->getFilters()) {
                    $res = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return $res;
    }

    /**
     * Return identifiers for produced content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return $this->getCurrentCategory()->getIdentities();
    }
}
```

Add block Path: `app\code\Vendor\AllProducts\Block\Index\Index.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\AllProducts\Block\Index;


class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context, array $data = []) {

        parent::__construct($context, $data);

    }


    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

}
```

Add Front controller, path should be like: `app\code\Vendor\AllProducts\Controller\Index\Index.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\AllProducts\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    private $context;
    private  $response;
    private  $redirect;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    private $url;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->context = $context;
        $this->response = $context->getResponse();
        $this->redirect = $context->getRedirect();
        $this->url = $url;
        //return 
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }

    public function getResponse()
    {
        return $this->response;
    }
}
```

Add `di.xml` in your module for overriding guidance
Path: `app\code\Vendor\AllProducts\etc\di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" type="Vendor\AllProducts\Block\Category\View" />
</config>

Override `catalog_category_view.xml` in your module. Path should be like: app\code\Vendor\AllProducts\view\frontend\layout\allproducts_index_index.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigationStaging\Block\Navigation\Category" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/view.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalog.navigation.state" as="state" />
                <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalog.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/filter.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
                    <container name="category.product.list.additional" as="additional" />
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="category.product.type.details.renderers.default" as="default"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="category.product.addto" as="addto">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                               name="category.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                               template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    </block>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
                    </action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```